# Why most of the minority carriers make it across the base as the base width is small?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, carrier-particles

I am studying about BJT from an online lecture note. I made a question in the image below. The reference in the image is from the two lectures, [lecture 18](http://alan.ece.gatech.edu/ECE3040/Lectures/Lecture18-BJT%20QuantitativePerformParameter.pdf) and [lecture 19](http://alan.ece.gatech.edu/ECE3040/Lectures/Lecture19-BJT%20Ebers-MollModel.pdf).

Could anyone help me with the question in the image?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When the hole concentration at the $x=0$ boundary is held constant at $n_0$ and holes are allowed to diffuse in the $0 < x < W$ region, they each travel a certain distance before being annihilated through recombination. The quantity $L_B$ in your notation represents the hole diffusion length, or the average distance traveled by diffusing holes during their average lifetime $\tau$.

When the diffusion length is large compared to the base width, $L_B >> W$, it means that most holes travel distances larger than $W$ before recombination, or else, that very few holes recombine while traveling a distance $W$. So the average concentration of holes surviving at the distal boundary of the base is comparable to their original concentration at the opposite boundary. And the lower the width $W$, the less the fraction of holes annihilated within the base.

If you prefer a quantitive treatment, the hole concentration at time $t$ and distance $x$ from the boundary  is given by [Ficks's diffusion laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fick%27s_laws_of_diffusion#Example_solution_in_one_dimension:_diffusion_length) as 
$$
n(x, t) = n_0 \,\text{erfc}\Big(\frac{x}{L_B}\sqrt{\frac{\tau}{t}}\Big)
$$
where erfc(x) is known as the complementary error function. Do not worry about its exact expression. What is important is that for distances $x$ much smaller than the diffussion length $L_B$, $x/L_B << 1$, its Taylor expansion is just $\text{erfc}(x) = 1 - 2 x/\sqrt{\pi}$. Which means that for small base widths, such that $x/L_B < W/ L_B << 1$, and for time scales on the order of the hole lifetime $t \sim \tau$, the hole concentration varies linearly with the distance $x$, 
$$
n(x) \approx n_0 \Big(1 - 2 \frac{x}{L_B}\Big)
$$
So at the other boundary of the base, for $x = W$, the concentration reads $n(W) \approx n_0 \Big(1 - 2 \frac{W}{L_B}\Big)$, which shows that the lower the width, the higher the surviving concentration.

Comment: Thanks. In your answer, at the boundary x=W you calculated the concentration from that equation. However, because the VCB is fixed so the hole concentration at that boundary should be fixed too. I believe that you should use the boundary in red box in my first post.

Comment: Right, forgot the voltage applied. So I wrote about diffusion current when the problem seems to be about the drift current. In this case the number of holes crossing the base is given by the current, which is obviously proportional to both the concentration and the electric field. Since the voltage bias and the concentrations are fixed, I would look at the electric field, which is roughly bias/width. Smaller width means higher electric field, faster drift velocity and larger current, so statistically, larger flux of holes across the base. I'll edit the answer later.